# Why my NSString to int is wrong in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, int

My problem is that the results of " R real:" is perfect but when I convert for exemple 'cloth.R' to int the result was 0. How can i solve it.
Thanks.

```
 Cloth *cloth = [app.clothArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"R real:%@",cloth.R);
 NSLog(@"G real:%@",cloth.G);
 NSLog(@"B real:%@",cloth.B);

NSString *aNumberString = cloth.R;
int i = [aNumberString intValue];
NSLog(@"NSString:%@",aNumberString);
NSLog(@"Int:%i",i);
```

Result:

```
2013-07-22 18:57:45.965 App_ermenegild[26030:c07] R real:
232
2013-07-22 18:57:45.965 App_ermenegild[26030:c07] G real:
0
2013-07-22 18:57:45.965 App_ermenegild[26030:c07] B real:
121
2013-07-22 18:57:45.966 App_ermenegild[26030:c07] NSString:
232
2013-07-22 18:57:45.966 App_ermenegild[26030:c07] Int:0
```

**Edit**
Here is `Cloth` class

```
@interface Cloth : NSObject 
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *nom; 
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *R; 
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *G; 
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *B; 
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *col; 
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger *clothID; 
@end
```

Here XML file pattern:

```
<cloth id="1">
<nom>Heliconia</nom>
<R>232</R>
<G>0</G>
<B>121</B>
<col>#E80079</col>
</cloth>
```

Comment: Is `cloth.R` definitely an `NSString` object?

Comment: ... and if it is, and is used to hold R,G,B values, then *why* is it an `NSString` object rather than an `int`?

Comment: why are you storing R,G,B in Cloth as NSString ?

Use CGFloat.

or better have UIColor property.

Comment: I can't offhand think of some scenario that would cause the above symptoms.  You need to show us the definition of Cloth, and how you set the R/G/B values.

Comment: @trojanfoe no it isn't
`@interface Cloth : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *nom;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *R;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *G;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *B;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *col;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger *clothID;

@end'

Comment: Show us how you set R/G/B.

Comment: Are you certain this is the exact code you are running?  Nothing you've left out or re-typed?  When running this code, I get correct results.

Comment: @Jim same here tried and tested this code with dummy data. but I'm getting exact result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only case where this comes is when you have invisible characters in the beginning e.g. new line character

e.g.

```
NSString *cloth = @"\n232";
int i = [cloth intValue];
NSLog(@"NSString:%@",cloth);
NSLog(@"Int:%i",i);
```

and the log is

```
2013-07-22 22:14:57.560 DeviceTest[801:c07] NSString:
232
2013-07-22 22:14:57.561 DeviceTest[801:c07] Int:0
```

That's why I asked you the exact log output.

Comment: yes, that's the exactly the problem that i have. But the spaces appears when I read and save it. I upload it.

Comment: And this is why I'd like to see where the RGB values are set.

Comment: @user2607430 where have you uploaded.. link please

Comment: Thanks I solve it eliminating the spaces on the ParserXML with that  currentElementValue =[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`%i` is not a [format specifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) for `NSString`.  The compiler and/or NSString should be warning you about that.</strike>

Well, damn. Learn something new everyday!  Still, use `%d` over `%i`.

Try `%d`.

```
NSLog(@"Int:%d",i);
```

---

If that doesn't work, then check to see if you have invisible character goobers in your string.  I'd suggest testing the length and see if it is a reasonable length.

It can be quite tricky to find that missing character because a number of unicode sequences will remain invisible in many contexts.   A hex editor can show you what is going on, but here is an an easy, hackish, test that'll work quite well for short strings.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *good = @"10";
        NSString *bad = @"1\u20630";

        NSLog(@"%@ %@", good, bad);

        NSLog(@"%d %d", [good intValue], [bad intValue]);

        NSData *dGood = [good dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSData *dBad = [bad dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@ %@", dGood, dBad);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2013-07-22 09:58:44.654 Untitled[1105:507] 10 1⁣0
2013-07-22 09:58:44.656 Untitled[1105:507] 10 1
2013-07-22 09:58:44.656 Untitled[1105:507] <3130> <31e281a3 30>
```

`0x31` is ASCII for the `1` character. `0x30` is `0`.  Obviously, the bad string has a bunch of gobbledygook between the 1 and the 0.   Convert your string to an NSData and log it.

---

In general, you should be using `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` to store numeric values *or* use bit-width specific types provided by the system.  It'll lead to less fragile code, especially if you turn on the "unsafe conversion" warning in the compiler.

Aside: if that really is a color, store it as an instance of `UIColor` or `NSColor`.   At least spell out the names of the components as it'll make the code read more fluently.

Comment: he's using %i for integer

Comment: The only thing they are logging with `%i` is the variable `i`, which is an `int`.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore `%i` does not mean "integer";  it doesn't mean anything.   `%d` means *Signed 32-bit integer*.

Comment: While `%i` is not an "official" NSString format character, it (usually) works.

Comment: @bbum, yes it does.  Read the page trojanfoe linked to - the table is a *summary*, and if you click through to the full specification, you will see that `%d` and `%i` are synonymous.

Comment: @HotLicks - it is official - click through to the full specification.  That table is just a summary.

Comment: @bbum yes Jim is right. I'm able to use %i in my test project. And here is the [IEEE docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html)  that specifies the format specifier

Comment: @user2607430 can you give the actual logs from your console. instead of typing manually in question. Like screen shot

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for upload images, sorry. But it's the same result with the %d. @InderKumarRathore

Comment: @user2607430 dude post it to any image hosting site and give us the link

Comment: @user2607430 In the debug console, "select" the text with your mouse and copy/paste it into your question, just like you (presumably) did with the source code.